# Wrong ClientID for dynamically added child control

Tags: c#, user-controls, webforms, parent-child, web-controls

I am trying to rework asp.net usercontrol with .ascx markup to WebControl(only .cs).

In my_new_webcontrol.cs I have:

```
private readonly DropDownList _source = new DropDownList();

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    _source.ID = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", ID, IdSeparator, "Source");
    Controls.Add(_source);
}

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    RenderContents(writer);
}

protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    _source.RenderControl(writer);
}
```

Problem is that it generates DropDownList with `id="MainContent_ComboBox1$Source"` and `name="ctl00$MainContent$ComboBox1$Source"`. Name generated as expected but Id wrong and here should be **_** instead of **$**.

How I can achieve `id="MainContent_ComboBox1_Source"` and `name="ctl00$MainContent$ComboBox1$Source"`.

**Update 1.**

Tried to put DropDownList into Panel as **Knaģis** suggested:

```
private readonly DropDownList _source = new DropDownList();
private readonly Panel _panel = new Panel();

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);
    _panel.ID = ID;
    _panel.Controls.Add(_source);
    Controls.Add(_panel);
}

protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    RenderContents(writer);
}

protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    _panel.RenderControl(writer);
}
```

No success. Generated HTML(ComboBox1 in id and name missing):

```
<div id="MainContent_ComboBox1">
    <select name="ctl00$MainContent$Source" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$MainContent$Source\',\'\')', 0)" id="MainContent_Source"></select>    
</div>
```

**Answer**

As **Knaģis** suggested I missed INamingContainer in my server control class declaration

```
public class ComboBox: WebControl, INamingContainer
```

Comment: I have no idea. [`Control.ClientIDSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidseparator.aspx) "always returns the underscore character(`_`)".

Comment: Than I will have d="MainContent_ComboBox1_Source" and name="ctl00$MainContent$ComboBox1_Source"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a child panel (or another container control) with ID of `ComboBox1` and then within that add your `DropDownList` with ID of `Source`. Let the ASP.NET generate the hierarchical identifiers.

In short - if you want to preserve the values of `ClientID` and `Name` for your reworked control, you should use the exact same control tree as your `.ascx` markup.

Comment: I didn't consider that because in original .ascx I have <asp:DropDownList ID="Source" runat="server"/> in the root of file and it generate select with correct id and name and without parent container.

Comment: Does ASP.NET by it self generate this IDs? I tried with panel as you suggested but no success(see Update 1.). I even tried to manually set ClientIDMode to Predictable

Comment: try creating a panel control like this: `public class ContainerPanel : Panel, INamingContainer { }`.

Comment: Oh nooo. So stupid =( Funny but I had question with INamingContainer on my 70-515 exam that I passed on Tuesday =)) Liels paldies, Knaģis.